# How to get activity list of Bitbucket Repository for a time period

Tags: python, git, api, bitbucket

I am using Bitbucket server (version v5.2.0). My goal is to get all the activity list of a particular repository in a specific time period.

I am trying with rest api's but i'm not able to get desired result.
Looked up here :https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-can-I-get-the-total-number-of-commits-across-all-our-team-s/qaq-p/136275

but the solution is not working for me.

Can you please help me here how to proceed further.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: year = 2017
        print ""
        print "Stats for {year}".format(year=year)
        print ""
        #query_url = self.api_url + 'projects/DETE/repos/core/commits'
        query_url = 'https://bitbucket.xxx.xxx/rest/api/1.0/projects/hello/repos/core/commits/
        print query_url
        try:
            req = urllib2.Request(query_url, None, {"Authorization": self._auth})
            handler = self._opener.open(req)
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            print e.headers
            raise e
        print simplejson.load(handler)

Comment: This gives only latest commits in all the branches of a repository. What I want if i pass say December 2017 how will i get all the activity list on that repo